# Add Script On Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-touch-punch, touch-punch

I have two scripts running at the same time. 1 is jqueryUI and the other is touchpunch. I have a signbox made in canvas where users can digitally sign. The problem occurs on the mobile. THe signature are draggable as they are on a contract. but on mobile phones draggable does not work. So I used touchpunch, it makes the draggable work on the mobile but at the same time clicking on the signature box turns off. CLicking on the sign box open a modal box where you can sign. If I put touchpunch at the bottom, draggable works and box opening stops. If I put jqueryUI at the bottom, the touch works but the draggable doesnt. What I'm trying to find a way to only put the jqueryUI only. and when the user clicks the box and the sign box opens, then touchpunch gets added at the end. So after signing touchpunch start working and the sign becomes draggable. What I have done so far is this:

```
        alert("appending");

        var x = document.createElement('script');
        x.src = '{{ asset("js/touchpunch.js") }}';
        document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(x);

        alert("done appending");

    }
```

When I inspect, I do see that after opening the box, the script does get added but the box still doesnt become draggable. The overall question is, how can I add one script onclick and make it work. Or if you have any other suggestion, please let me know.

Comment: `but on mobile phones draggable does not work` have you at all looked into a cross-browser solution? I'm seeing some vanilla javascript in your solution.

Comment: Thats what I have written, the touchpunch script enables the draggable on mobile

Comment: Ok on that part. But you do have vanilla javascript. No telling what a given phone would do. Is why a cross browser library (e.g. jquery) would come in handy. I upvoted you by the way to bring this some attention your problem.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate that. I just need to know how can I enable or disable a javascript on click.

Comment: No no sir. Here let me explain a bit. There are two scripts like these. they are cdn's.
<script src="jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="touchpunch.js"></script>
What I want to do is not include the touchpunch one. But if user click on a specific button. this scripts gets included. I am not talking about the browser JS enable or disable